# filtering date column that contains strings as well in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Good Day,
 i have an MS Access DB that has 1 column that contains dates and strings (in different cells). my question is if it is possible to filter by date as date while keeping the strings? the column looks like this:

`Date_Col
 01/05/15
 05/04/18
 Not Released
 01/01/18
 Not Released`

this is data from hardware EOL so we need to keep the dates and the strings but we need to have the ability to filter or sort the dates as we wish.
any help would be appreciated as right now when i am trying to filter the column is treating everything as text but if the column was in excel it will filter by date and ignore the strings cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query where you convert that text field to a true date value:

```
Select *, CDate([Date_Col]) As TrueDate
From YourTable
Where IsDate([Date_Col])
```

Now, filter on field TrueDate as you like.

Comment: that works converting text dates to proper dates but the cells in that column that contain strings turn into errors (#ERROR) so when i try to apply the filter it does not work

Comment: No, #Error must be caused by something else. The query can't change the original field, `Date_Col`. A filter must be applied to field `TrueDate`.